# Limited-Alphabet String

Tags: python

I have a very long string with a limited alphabet of 4. Can I store this string differently so it takes up less space since it has a small alphabet as opposed to a normal string? Within my code I never edit this string, and only access characters at indexes. If it helps this is for a genome alignment algorithm, the alphabet is ACTG.

Comment: 4 distinct values means you can pack it on bit level: 2 bits per position, 4 characters per byte.

Comment: How long is "very long"? A few million letters is nothing. As @Organis mentions, you _could_ pack that down to 2 bits per DNA base, but that's not convenient to work with in Python. You could use a `bytes` string, which will use 1 byte per letter for the actual DNA bases, plus a small amount of constant overhead for the `bytes` object itself. But that's pretty much the same space as what a normal text (Unicode) string uses for simple ASCII characters.

Comment: Is a few million letters really nothing? I tried to look online for a conversion rate between string length and storage space and didn't find anything... bytes seem interesting to me I will look into using this

Comment: A million letters takes about 1 megabyte. I assume you have a gigabyte or 2 of RAM to spare on your machine. FWIW, in Python 3.6, a bytes string takes 17 bytes plus one byte per char, a string takes 25 bytes, plus 1 byte per ASCII char.

Comment: Without more details about what sort of processing you need to perform on the string, it's hard to make a concrete recommendation. Unless you find it impossible to fit your draw data into memory, the complications probably vastly dominate over the benefits. The reason you load something into memory is usually that you need random access (quickly pick out a value at any arbitrary offset). If that's not what you need, not loading all the data at once might be a much simpler option to explore.

Comment: You have stated your aim. Perhaps you should add what you tried as well.

Comment: I haven't really tried anything besides trying fairly hard to search a way and finding nothing