# Shorten long small-alphabet string using larger alphabet

Tags: python, encoding

I have a set of ~100 long (between 120 and 150 characters) strings encoded using a 20 letter alphabet (the natural amino acid alphabet). I'm using them in database entries, but they're cumbersome. I'd like to shorten (not compressing, because I don't care about the memory size) them to make them easier to:

- Visually compare
- Copy/Paste
- Manually enter

I was hoping a feasible way to shorten them would be convert the string to a larger alphabet. Specifically, the set of single digits, as well as lower and upper case alphabet.

For example:

```py
# given some long string as input
shorten("ACTRYP...TW")
# returns something shorter like "a3A4n"
```

### Possible approaches

From my elementary understanding of compression, this could be accomplished naively by making a lookup dictionary which maps certain repeating sequences elements of the larger alphabet.

### Related Question

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50894017/1079075) seemed to pointing in a similar direction, but was working with the DNA alphabet and seemed to be actually seeking compression.

Comment: This is "encoding", not "compression". Please give a full example of how `a3A4n` is the same as `ACTRYP...TW`

Comment: You can treat your 20 letter alphabet encoded string as a number in 20 base number and convert it into a lowercase + uppercase ascii + 0-8 (sexagesimal)

Comment: @DaniMesejo I hadn't thought of that! Seems like a legitimate answer to me and bypasses all the complexity of compression.

Comment: Option 1, `hex(hash(string)).strip('-')[2:][:7]`. This hashes your string (ensures it's unique) and then selects the first 7 digits after the `0x` and negative sign. Option 2, encode it in Base64: `base64.encodestring(string.encode())`

Comment: @thethiny I thought the hash would make my string longer, but it worked, proving to me I don't understand hashing. The `base64` method somehow made my string longer, which means I should post a longer example.

Comment: Do the same [:7] thing again. You can also uuid.uuid4(string)

Comment: @thethiny what's the purpose of `[:7]`? How much does it increase the collision probability?

Comment: `[:7]` limits it to the first 7 characters. `[FROM:TO]` is the syntax. Github uses 7 letters to identify commits, so I believe it's safe to use the first 7 letters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @thethiny a combination of hashing can accomplish the shortening desired:

```py
import base64
import hashlib

kinda_long = "ELYWPSRVESGTLVGYQYGRAITGQGKTSGGGSGWLGGGLRLSALELSGKTFSCDQAYYQVLSLNRGVICFLKVSTSVWSYESAAGFTMSGSAQYDYNVSGKANRSDMPTAFDVSGA"
shorter = base64.b32encode(hashlib.sha256(af.encode()).digest()).decode().strip("=")
```

My original question mentioned using ASCII alphabet and digits. This would be a base 62 encoding. Various libraries exist for this.